# Local vars interfere with $_SESSION vars?

Tags: php, session-variables

The output of the following code on a random page is :

```
            print $_SESSION['uid']; // logged in user
        // Get Data .
        $uid = $_GET['ID']; // part of random page processing
            print $_SESSION['uid'];
```

is :

```
1
2
```

My logged in User ID is changing ! :@

The code for the login (authenticate) page is something like this :

```
        // Authenticate
        $query = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE Email = '".$Email."' AND Password = '".$Password."'";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        // Authenticated?
        if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
            // Yes

            // Set session Vars
            $uid = mysql_result($result,0,ID);
            $Access = mysql_result($result,0,Access);

            session_destroy();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['loggedIN'] = 1;
            $_SESSION['Access'] = $Access;
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;

            // Print a successful login and redirect
```

Comment: BTW, `session_destroy` does not delete the `$_SESSION` array. It is a known bug.

Comment: Really? :o Then what would be a the right procedure to clear out any vars?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're seeing is a side-effect of [`register_globals`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.register-globals). Basically:

```
$uid
```

and

```
$_SESSION['uid']
```

reference the same variable so when you do:

```
$uid = $_GET['ID'];
```

it's the equivalent of:

```
$SESSION['uid'] = $_GET['ID'];
```

My advice? Turn off register globals. It's deprecated in PHP 5.3 and will be removed in PHP 6. To turn it off, edit your php.ini file and change to this directive:

```
register_globals = Off
```

then restart Apache (or whatever your Web server is).

Answer (score 2):

That's weird... Are you sure you're not doing `$_SESSION['uid']++` anywhere?

Also, do you have `register_globals` on?

Comment: BTW, I'm beating you by 4 Rep!

Comment: No, i guess that's the problem :)

Comment: @Chacha102: Haha, not anymore! :P

Comment: Just you wait ... I'll be ahead of you soon enough.

Answer (score 1):

`register_globals` should be off by default.

Is there some call to [`session_register`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php) anywhere?

Comment: I'm on php5.2.8. And i haven't meddled with the config. And no.