# Strange PHP variable behavior with $_SESSION set before local vars

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session-variables

I am working on a small eCommerce site which is using a simple user log-in system.

I am testing by setting the id in the database as a $_SESSION var so I can keep track of some other stuff.

There was an odd problem where PHP was not setting the proper values to variables IF the $_SESSION var was set before I did a comparison, and I would love to know why.

This IF statement shows the session var commented out, but this is where it was placed initially. In this placement, the IF returned false (even if i cast the var as INT) and the token value only returned the first digit.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("select id, token, confirmed from customers where email = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($email));
$customerId = $stmt->fetchAll();    
$customerId = $customerId[0];

if (!empty($customerId))
{
    //$_SESSION['customerId'] = $customerId['id'];

    if ($customerId['confirmed'] == 0)
    {
        $sendConfirm = 1;
        $uuid = $customerId['token'];

        echo $sendConfirm."/".$customerId['token'];
    }
}
```

I know this sounds crazy, but if I moved the session var under the IF or removed it, everything works as expected. This is PHP 5.4.

Can anyone think of a reason why this would happen?

Comment: I'm thinking your question is related to this one (issue is related to register_globals): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079710/local-vars-interfere-with-session-vars?rq=1

Comment: I'd hate to answer my own question, so you can if you like. That was right, the $_SESSION['customerId'] was getting confused with $customerId. I changed $customerId to $customerIdx and everything worked. Whew, I thought I had lost it. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason I would strictly recommend you to get that register_globals turned off (if it could be done without breaking whole site, of course) instead of renaming a variable.

Comment: Luckily the site is in its infancy and I was just testing something, so no big deal. But I will turn it off. I am surprised I have never ran into this before today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is the session variable has the same name as a local variable.

This has happened to me before and I feel your pain.

Comment: It is actually. This is solved one of two ways, rename the variables, or the safer better way, turn off register_globals. I figured this out, but no one ever put up an answer and I forgot about it until now :)